# How to delete rows or column in ILArray like Matlab, ILNumerics

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, matrix, ilnumerics

In ILArray of ILNumerics library, is there any shortcut to delete the row or columns like matlab?

Something like this (in matlab):

```
A(:,2)=[];
A(2,:)=[];
```

Since the ILNumerics is very similar with Matlab, I curious about this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Empty() method of ILMath class.

for example :  A[1, ":"] = ILMath.Empty()